# C# Bug? - System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error even tho the strings that i want to call to a function aren't null

[image]

(As you can see in pic the string isn't null)

This is the error

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
>     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I even added some code to "handle", I mean to see if the strings are null, and they aren't but still it shows the error

```
if (opp1name != null && opp2name != null && opp3name != null)
```

This may be useful too?

[image]

Comment: Why do you focus on the string? Is `pl` `null`?

Comment: Look at the code closer. The `pl` is null.

Comment: Show us the actual code that is producing this exception, not the null check's you are doing.

Comment: @HighCore Notice the little question mark after "Bug", it means he's not sure.  He's not blaming anything.  Chill out.

Comment: @AaronLS haha yea man, HighCore peace bro :D my fault

Comment: It will not in itself lead to an exception to pass a `null` reference as an argument to a method. As in `pl.Send(null, null, null, null)`. Of course that method might throw an exception if it doesn't like its input. However accessing an instance member, like an instance method, through a `null` reference _always_ leads to a `NullReferenceException`. So `pl == null` is what everyone should think when the exception comes from that line. (Calling an extension method on a null reference, or calling an instance method on a `Nullable<>` instance which does not `HasValue`, does not give exception.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This could also occur if `pl` is `null`, or if something required within the `pl.Send` method (aside from the passed arguments) is `null`.

Make sure to properly instantiate `pl` (so it is not null), as this is the most likely cause of the issue.

Comment: Yes, probably look at the stack trace in more detail or step into the Send method if possible.

Comment: lol changed to if (pl != null) and it worked, such a stupid mistake :) thanks!

Comment: @user2624407 that may prevent the NullPointerException from showing up, but I bet your method is not executed. I don't think that's what you want to achieve, so it's best to step into that Send() method to find out what's going wrong (or find out why p1 is null).